# Has anbody used Boo and can you comment on your experiences?

Tags: .net, dynamic-languages, boo

I'm looking for a groovy equivalent on .NET
http://boo.codehaus.org/

So far Boo looks interesting, but it is statically typed, yet does include some of the metaprogramming features I'd be looking for.

Can anyone comment on the experience of using Boo and is it worth looking into for more than hobby purposes at a 1.0 Version?

*Edit*: Changed BOO to Boo

Comment: Just did.     10 char min filler...

Comment: Btw: Boo 0.9 has recently been released: http://blogs.codehaus.org/people/bamboo/archives/001749_boo_09_is_here.html

Comment: Can you add the tag "boo?" I have is as a favorite.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Boo quite a lot lately.  It's very flexible and very powerful.  The metaprogramming works well, but it's not nearly as easy to use as Nemerle's.  In addition, the lack of arbitrary expression nesting (e.g. def foo = if(bar) match(baz) { ... } else 0;) makes certain things harder than it has to be, but that's not something you're going to miss unless you're coming from Nemerle, OCaml, Haskell, or something along those lines.

Overall, I'd say give it a shot.  I don't think you'll be disappointed.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a paper on it for my programming language class. I was really impressed with it. It's very fun, and they've started working on BooLangStudio. SharpDevelop also has some support for it.

There are a lot of things that I liked about it. When BooLangStudio will be released with code complition, and boo compiler reaches 1.0 ( that means that the compiler will be written in pure boo :D ) I'll definitely be considering it over C#. It's awesome so you won't regret looking into it!